# How to detect I am running on IBM bluemix?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud

How can I check my app runs on IBM Bluemix compute nodes? Can I detect it using `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`?

Comment: The question is confusing. Are you looking for application logic to determine if the application is currently running in Bluemix?

Comment: Yes. I think the question description clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running as a cloud foundry application, you can check for the presence of the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I think every application which runs on Bluemix may not be necessarily running through cloud foundry. I'm looking for a more generic solution.